# Write down the irreducible representations of $G = C_2 \times C_3 = \langle g_1, g_2 \, : \, g_1^2 = g_2^3 = 1, g_1g_2 = g_2g_1 \rangle$

Tags: representation-theory

Write down the irreducible representations of
$$
G = C_2 \times C_3 = \langle g_1, g_2 \, : \, g_1^2 = g_2^3 = 1, g_1g_2 = g_2g_1 \rangle
$$
The answer I am given is:

There are six $1$ dimensional representations determined by

$$
\begin{align}
g_1 &\mapsto \pm 1 \\
g_2 &\mapsto e^{\frac{2ik\pi}{3}} \text{ for } k=0,1,2
\end{align}
$$

I understand how they obtained the values for $g_1$ because $g^2_1$=1, so $g_1$ could be either $1$ or $-1$, but why do you get the roots of unity for $g_2$?

Thanks.

Comment: Because $g_2^3 = 1$...

Comment: but the cube root of 1 is 1, this is where I am getting confused

Comment: No, $1$ has three cube roots, just like it has two square roots. The square roots of $1$ are $\pm 1$ (which can be rewritten as $e^{\frac{2ik\pi}{2}}$). The cube roots of $1$ are $e^{\frac{2ik\pi}{3}}$.

Comment: oh of course, that is really stupid of me. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  You get roots of unity for $g_1$, as well.

Comment: I am confused because the cube root of 1 is just 1

Comment: don't worry I understand now I was missing the point completely! thanks anyway